# Looping through multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Please refer to array below. What I would like to do is to get the total of the values of index zero under 21 and 23 divided by the number of zeros. It is like getting their average.

```
Array
(
[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3.5
        [65] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44.125
            )

        [150] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15.25
            )

        [151] => Array
            (
                [0] => 17.333333333333
            )

    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [166] => Array
            (
                [0] => 26
            )

        [172] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [182] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20.333333333333
            )

        [183] => Array
            (
                [0] => 24.125
            )

    )

)
```

Then format it to this

```
Array
(
[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => Average for 21
        [65] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44.125
            )

        [150] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15.25
            )

        [151] => Array
            (
                [0] => 17.333333333333
            )

    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => Average for 23
        [166] => Array
            (
                [0] => 26
            )

        [172] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [182] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20.333333333333
            )

        [183] => Array
            (
                [0] => 24.125
            )

    )

)
```

Thanks in advance to those who can help! :)

Note: This is just a sample structure of the array. It's possible that the children of 21 and 23 can have another children, meaning, another nodes. Example:

```
 [65] => Array
    (
        [0] => 44.125
        [x] => Array
          (
              [0]=> 121.11
          )
   )
```

I believe a recursive function is needed on this one.

Comment: use var_export($array) instead of print_r($array) to post Array structure here.

Comment: you want to add [0] => 3.5 in array 21 and divide it by 4

Comment: @RohitAwasthi noted. sorry bout that. this is my first time here. thanks.

@ karth all those that have index 0 under 21 should be added then divided by the number of index 0..any idea?

Comment: @user3360031 i have posted a solution. I think this is what you was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think this is what you want

```
   $count1 = 0;$sum=0;
    $count2 = 0;$sum2=0;
    foreach ($array as $key3 => $value3) 
    {
      if($key3 == "21")
      {
        foreach ($value3 as $key => $value)
        {
          if (strpos($key, '0') === 0) {
            $count1++;$sum=$sum+$value;
           }
           if(is_array($value))
           { 
             foreach($value as $key2=>$value2)
             {
               if(strpos($key2,'0') === 0)
               {
                 $count1++ ;$sum=$sum+$value2;
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
      if($key3 == "23")
      {
        foreach ($value3 as $key => $value)
        {
          if (strpos($key, '0') === 0) {
            $count2++;$sum2=$sum2+$value;
           }
           if(is_array($value))
           { 
             foreach($value as $key2=>$value2)
             {
               if(strpos($key2,'0') === 0)
               {
                 $count2++; $sum2=$sum2+$value2;
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }


$array[21][0] = ($sum/$count1);
$array[23][0] = ($sum2/$count2);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/clLWl)

Comment: thanks. however the array is actually dynamic. i forgot to mention it in my post. i edited my post for clarification. thanks.

Comment: also does the main array has only 21 and 23 ?

Comment: it's a complicated array. the indexes you see are actually IDs of a hierarchy. Example: the 21 may represent 'CEO' then the IDs below him are his managers. his managers can have members also, so on and so forth. so it's really a dynamic array. i cant tell how many level it goes. that's why i believe it requires a recursive function to solve this. correct me if im wrong, though. thanks!

Comment: In that case you are correct. You need recursive function. I will edit the answer if got any answers to help you.